# How to return a resultset / cursor from a Oracle PL/SQL anonymous block that executes Dynamic SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this table:

```
ALLITEMS
---------------
ItemId  | Areas
---------------
1       | EAST
2       | EAST
3       | SOUTH
4       | WEST
```

The DDL:

```
drop table allitems;

Create Table Allitems(ItemId Int,areas Varchar2(20));
Insert Into Allitems(Itemid,Areas) Values(1,'east');
Insert Into Allitems(ItemId,areas) Values(2,'east');
insert into allitems(ItemId,areas) values(3,'south');
insert into allitems(ItemId,areas) values(4,'east');
```

In MSSQL, to get a cursor from a dynamic SQL I can do:

```
DECLARE @v_sqlStatement VARCHAR(2000);
SET @v_Sqlstatement = 'SELECT * FROM ALLITEMS';
EXEC (@v_sqlStatement); --returns a resultset/cursor, just like calling SELECT
```

In Oracle, I need to use a PL/SQL Block:

```
SET AUTOPRINT ON;
DECLARE
 V_Sqlstatement Varchar2(2000);
 outputData SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 V_Sqlstatement := 'SELECT * FROM ALLITEMS';
 OPEN outputData for v_Sqlstatement; 
End;
--result is : anonymous block completed
```

**But all I get is

> anonymous block completed".

How do I get it to return the cursor?

(*I know that if I do AUTOPRINT, it will print out the information in the REFCURSOR (it's not printing in the code above, but thats another problem)*)

I will be calling this Dynamic SQL from code (ODBC,C++), and I need it to return a cursor. How?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can write a PL/SQL function to return that cursor (or you could put that function in a package if you have more code related to this):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_allitems
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM allitems;
  RETURN my_cursor;
END get_allitems;
```

This will return the cursor.

Make sure not to put your `SELECT`-String into quotes in PL/SQL when possible. Putting it in strings means that it can not be checked at compile time, and that it has to be parsed whenever you use it.

---

If you really need to use dynamic SQL you can put your query in single quotes:

```
  OPEN my_cursor FOR 'SELECT * FROM allitems';
```

This string has to be parsed whenever the function is called, which will usually be slower and hides errors in your query until runtime.

Make sure to use bind-variables where possible to avoid [hard parses](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2588723819082):

```
  OPEN my_cursor FOR 'SELECT * FROM allitems WHERE id = :id' USING my_id;
```

Comment: @Peter Lang: How would you call the function in this case?

Comment: @MissPiplup: I fixed the broken link, does this help you?

Comment: Yeah it does. My apologies for the late reply.

Comment: how can we return rows instead of cursor ? @PeterLang that referemce link is broken

Comment: @MustangManiac: Removed the broken link as it was not part of the question anyway. Not sure what you mean by "return rows" but this sounds like a different question. Try to find existing questions or ask a new one. Good luck!

Comment: @PeterLang, i'm a bit confused by this-- i thought the OP wants to make dynamic sql, not hard-coded. You say not to put the select string in quotes "if possible". So, this will work with sql as a string?

Comment: @johnywhy: Exactly. I edited this into my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: @PeterLang, thx for the examples, esp the USING example. Thx for the tip on hard parsing!

Answer (score 9):

in SQL*Plus you could also use a `REFCURSOR` variable:

```
SQL> VARIABLE x REFCURSOR
SQL> DECLARE
  2   V_Sqlstatement Varchar2(2000);
  3  BEGIN
  4   V_Sqlstatement := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  5   OPEN :x for v_Sqlstatement;
  6  End;
  7  /

ProcÚdure PL/SQL terminÚe avec succÞs.

SQL> print x;

D
-
X
```

Comment: But does the "print x" return a cursor? I need to call this PL/SQL block from C++ code and so I need it to return a cursor. Or is there a way to access "x" from code?

Comment: @Liao: X is the cursor, you should be able to access it like an OUT variable if you call the PL/SQL Block from C++. `print` however is a SQL*Plus command and won't work outside of SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to declare a cursor to be a bind variable (called parameters in other DBMS')

like Vincent wrote, you can do something like this:

```
begin
  open :yourCursor
    for 'SELECT "'|| :someField ||'" from yourTable where x = :y'
      using :someFilterValue;
end;
```

You'd have to bind 3 vars to that script. An input string for "someField", a value for "someFilterValue" and an cursor for "yourCursor" which has to be declared as output var.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how you'd do that from C++. (One could say fortunately for me, though. ;-) )

Depending on which access library you use, it might be a royal pain or straight forward.

Answer (score -7):

This setting needs to be set:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```